# Use the Intermediate Value Theorem to show the equation

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, continuity

Use the intermediate value theorem to show that the equation, 
$ tan(x) = 2x $ 
has an infinite amount of real solutions.

So far I have used the IVT to show that for $ f(x) = tan(x) $ in the interval $ (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}) $ there is a $ L $ between $ -\infty $ and $ \infty $ such that there is a value $c$ where $ f(c) = L $

I also have shown that for $ g(x) = 2x $ in the interval $ [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}] $ there is a $ K $ between $ -\pi $ and $ \pi $ such that there is a value $d$ where $ f(d) = K $

Would it be correct to say that because each of these functions have a value for each point in the interval and that the range of $f(x)$ consists of all reals that $f(x)$ must intersect with $g(x)$ or there is some value $x$ in the interval such that $2x = tan(x) $? If this is correct then how would I extend this result to all intervals $ [\pi(n - \frac{1}{2}), \pi(n + \frac{1}{2})] $?

Comment: The intermediate value theorem shows that a solution exists in $(-{\pi \over 2}, {\pi \over 2})$ and periodicity shows the rest.

Comment: in fact you can say more that the roots $x_n = \pi/2 + n\pi$ as $n \to \pm \infty$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=\tan(x)-2x$. 
Then $f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{\cos^2(x)}-2.$

On ($\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}$) and ($-\frac{\pi}{2},-\frac{\pi}{4}$), $f'(x)>0$.

Since $\lim \limits_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}{-}}f'(x)=+\infty, \lim \limits_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}{-}}f(x)=+\infty$.

Similarly since $\lim \limits_{x\to-\frac{\pi}{2}{+}}f'(x)=-\infty, \lim \limits_{x\to-\frac{\pi}{2}{+}}f(x)=-\infty$.

So $\exists x_1\in (-\frac{\pi}{2},-\frac{\pi}{4})$, such that, $f(x_1)<0$, and $\exists x_2\in (\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2})$, such that $f(x_2)>0$. By intermediate value theorem, $\exists x_0, x_1<x_0<x_2, f(x_0)=0$ since $f(x)$ is continuous.

Same reasoning can be applied to ($-\dfrac{\pi}{2}+k\pi,\dfrac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$), $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. So there are infinite real solution for $f(x)$.